# Inverse Function of a Set

Tags: functions

Let there be a function f and sets X and Y.

$f: X \rightarrow Y$

is $f^{-1}(Y) = X$?

Comment: Try using your definitions.  Recall... $f^{-1}(B) = \{x\in X~:~\exists b\in B~\text{such that}~f(x)=b\}$.  Now... for each $x\in X$... does there infact exist some $y\in Y$ such that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: For what it's worth, since it is not given that $f$ is surjective, I would have expressed the conclusion differently.  Let $Y_1 \subseteq Y$ be such that $f(X) = Y_1$.  Then $f^{-1}(Y_1) = X$, while $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily defined for all of $Y$.  Also, since it is not given that $f$ is injective, the function $f^{-1}$ might not even be well defined, even restricting attention to the range (i.e. codomain) of $f$.

Comment: @user2661923 the notation $f^{-1}$ here is for the inverse relation, not the inverse function.  Similar but different concepts

Comment: @JMoravitz Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{ x\in X : f(x)\in Y\}$. As $Y$ is the codomain of $f(x)$, then $f(x)\in Y$ for every $x\in X$ and so, consequently, $f^{-1}(Y) = X$.

Comment: thanks bruv for the help